# Align subscripted axis labels in R

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting a box plot in R whose labels include some super- and sub-scripts. R seems to align these labels along their bottoms, not on the text baseline, making them look very uneven. Is there a way to align the labels on their text baselines, so the "ABC" in each would align?

```
ns = c("ABC", expression("ABC"^"+"), expression("ABC"["DEF"]), expression("ABC"["DEF"]^"+"), "ABC")
boxplot(1:3, 2:4, 3:5, 1:4, 4:5, names=ns)
```

[image: Box plot with misaligned labels]

So far I have tried adding an empty subscript to all the labels, which helped a little, but did not actually bring them into alignment.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work out that I need *both* a dummy subscript and a dummy superscript in order to get the labels aligned.

The superscripts affect the positioning of the subscripts. See for example that the "DEF" in the 3rd and 4th columns are at different heights compared to the "ABC". This is not a problem except that it affect the baseline.

The following hack has all labels aligned:

```
ns = c(expression("ABC"[""]^""), expression("ABC"[""]^"+"), expression("ABC"["DEF"]^""), expression("ABC"["DEF"]^"+"), expression("ABC"[""]^""))
boxplot(1:3, 2:4, 3:5, 1:4, 4:5, names=ns)
```